# Joining tables that compute values between dates

Tags: sql, impala

so I have the two following tables

Table A

```
Date        num
01-16-15    10
02-20-15    12
03-20-15    13
```

Table B

```
Date        Value
01-02-15    100
01-03-15    101
   .         .
01-17-15    102
01-18-15    103
   .         .
02-22-15    104
   .         .
03-20-15    110
```

And i want to create a table that have the the following output in impala

```
Date         Value
01-17-15     102*10
01-18-15     103*10
02-22-15     104*12
   .           .
   .           .
```

So the idea is that we only consider dates between 01-16-15 and 02-20-15, and 02-20-15 and 03-20-15 exclusively. And use the num from the starting date of that period, say 01-16-15, and multiply it by everyday in the period, i.e. 1-16 to 2-20.

I understand it should be done by join but I am not sure how do you join in this case.
Thanks!

Comment: If you are considering dates in that range, why doesn't the result set have all the dates you are considering?

Comment: Because each date between 1-16 and 2-20 will be consider as period 1, and period 1 will use 1-16 to determine values within it, i.e. 1-17

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. In standard SQL you can do:

```
select b.*,
       (select a.num
        from a
        where a.date <= b.date
        order by a.date desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) * value as new_value
from b;
```

I don't think this meets the range conditions, but I don't understand your description of that.

I also don't know if Impala supports correlated subqueries.  An alternative is probably faster on complex data:

```
with ab as (
      select a.date, a.value as a_value, null as b_value, 'a' as which
      from a
      union all
      select b.date, null as a_value, b_value, 'b' as which
      from b
     )
select date, b_value * a_real_value
from (select ab.*,
             max(a_value) over (partition by a_date) as a_real_value
      from (select ab.*,
                   max(a.date) over (order by date, which) as a_date
            from ab
           ) ab
     ) ab
where which = 'b';
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on MariaDb (MySql) and it's pretty basic so hopefully it works on impala too.

```
SELECT b.date, b.value * a.num
FROM tableB b, tableA a
WHERE b.date >= a.date
  AND (b.date < (SELECT MIN(c.date) FROM tableA c WHERE c.date > a.date)
       OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT c.date FROM tableA c WHERE c.date > a.date))
```

The last NOT EXISTS... was needed to include dates after the last date in table A

**Update**
In the revised version of the question the date in B is never larger (after) the last date in A so then the query can be written as

```
SELECT b.date, b.value * a.num
FROM tableB b, tableA a
WHERE b.date >= a.date
  AND b.date <= (SELECT MIN(c.date) FROM tableA c WHERE c.date > a.date)
```

Comment: Can you explain a litter more about the function of AND here? And also there is a typo in the problem statement and I have already fixed it. Basically, the last date of two tables are the same, in this case, we do not need the NOT EXISTS clause right?

Comment: "condition1 AND condition2" this means that both conditions needs to be true. So here it means that b.date needs to be >= date from A and less than the next date in table A

Comment: So for the revised version where the last date are the same for both tables, we only need  AND (b.date < (SELECT MIN(c.date) FROM tableA c WHERE c.date > a.date) right？

Comment: No, you'll still need the complete WHERE clause from my answer

Comment: OK. Just tried it in impala and returns the error:Subqueries in OR predicates are not supported. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Actually I was wrong earlier, for the revised version we can skip the OR part. I'll update my answer.